# Is there a maven plugin to do wsdl to java with xstream mappings?

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, xstream, wsdl2java, xml-binding

At present i know that there is a plugin called cxf-codegen plugin which converts wsdl to java  with jaxb bindings .At present I just give the wsdl file and xsd file , the maven cxf-codegen plugin takes care of conversion fron wsdl to java with default jaxb bindings. I am searching for a solution as simple as that .

The system I am going to work with uses xstream.So I need to find a maven plugin to do wsdl to java with xstream bindings . The system uses restlet as rest framework .

Is there anything available as such ?

Thanks